# Openlayers 3 Handle tile load error

Tags: openlayers-3, tile

I know there is a `tileloaderror` event fired if a tile fails to load, but how do I use that event to replace the missing tile with a 256x256 transparent png?  At the moment if a tile is missing and you zoom in then the zoomed out portion of the tile is still available, I want to replace it with a blank to stop this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set value of [useInterimTilesOnError](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/apidoc/ol.layer.Tile.html#getUseInterimTilesOnError) to false

Comment: Perfect!  That worked a treat - no longer getting 'spill over' from missing tiles on a layer above my map layer.  Thanks.